# What does it mean to "restart" a program (in my case IDLE)?

Tags: python, python-idle

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37898012/3001761) on Stack Overflow offers a solution I am trying to implement.  In particular, see the sections "Installation Instructions" and "How to Use".

Can anyone tell me the steps required to "restart" IDLE?

**New Information:**

Just as people have suggested I thought this simply meant closing the program and opening it back up again...but **I already tried that**.

The other twist to my situation is that I'm working on a virtual machine so I was unable to do the installation of IDLE2HTML.py myself.  My work's Help Desk had to do it so I cannot speak for the accuracy of their work.  For now I'm assuming they did it correctly, but when I go to the "Options" menu there is no option to "Save as HTML".

My only guess at this point is that I still need to "restart IDLE".

Just wanted to double check if there was something else I could do before going back to my Help Desk department.

Comment: Quit IDLE. Launch IDLE again.

Comment: Some programs support `exec`ing themselves, to replace their image in memory with a completely new copy, but that's not by any means a necessary approach.

Comment: The same way you restart any other application, like a web browser or mail program.

Comment: @jonrsharpe... Thanks, I already tried closing and relaunching Python.  Please see new edits to my question.

Comment: That is restarting IDLE. Also please learn from the edits people make to your questions: don't put *pictures of text content* in them, images are far less accessible, harder to copy-paste sections of, don't scale to other resolutions, ...

Comment: @jonrsharpe... sorry, the screen grab contained no code and I didn't foresee anyone wanting to copy/paste from it... it was just intended to save people the effort of digging through the other thread.    Nonetheless, the pic has been removed.  The real issue is that I have restarted IDLE but the problem persists.  I'll check with my Help Desk to make sure the installation was done correctly.

Comment: Then you could have posted it **as text**, like I did when editing. You hadn't actually provided a link to the other thread, so I had to find that, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDLE reads the `idlelib/config-xyz.def` files, including `config-extensions.def`, just once, when it starts.  So any changes to `config-extensions.def` only takes effect the next time you start IDLE.

If you do not see 'Save as HTML' after starting IDLE, the extension is not installed properly.

Comment: - thanks Terry, that is the correct answer.  My issue was that since I'm working on a virtual machine that I don't have permissions to alter, the upgrading process was out of my hands and up to my Help Desk dept.  I just wanted to quickly check with the online community in case there was something else causing the lack of success with the upgrade.  Turns out my Help Desk technician made the installation on the wrong license.  Looking back I can see how this question came off as elementary to others on here.  Thank you for addressing the issue with care and consideration.

Comment: Also, I don't regret asking the question because it was useful to me, but because the background to the question (virtual machine out of my control) was so unique to me I doubt it will serve many others on here.  For that reason I plan to delete this question before I suffer too many more down votes.

Answer (score 0):

It means you need to close the IDLE so that any changes made by the script can affect the IDLE

Simply close the IDLE either via the `X`, `Ctrl+Q` or `File>Exit`, then open the IDLE again.

If you are using idlelib module from a Python program then close your program and run it again.